# What happened to my video and audio strips?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I was just cutting and moving part of the video i was editing, when i accidently changed the view of the strips, i can't see them but they are still there. I don't know if a pressed a key or clicked something by accident. Can someone explain please?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot? Are you sure you're in the right scene and not scrolled away from the clips?

Answer (score 1):

Try Frame All in the View menu:

[image]